# Finding the Cosine of the Central Angle

Tags: trigonometry, products

Show that $$\cos\theta = \cos(60^\circ)\cos(25^{\circ})\cos(48^{\circ})\cos(-122^{\circ})+\cos(60^{\circ})\sin(25^{\circ})\cos(48^{\circ})\sin(-122^{\circ})+\sin(60^{\circ})\sin(48^{\circ}) = 0.36299$$

The answer shows 0.36299 (68.716 degrees) but the answer I got was 0.704055146
I calculated it several times but still got the same wrong answer. What am I doing wrong? Yes--I did use a calculator. The calculator is in degrees, and yes--all angles are degrees.

Comment: are all angles in degrees?

Comment: Are you using a calculator or is this by hand?

Comment: he must use a calculator

Comment: you must use DEG at your calculator!

Comment: I don't know what else we can do for you. The answer is here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Cos%5B60+Pi%2F180%5D+Cos%5B25+Pi%2F180%5D+Cos%5B48+Pi%2F180%5D+Cos%5B-122+Pi%2F180%5D+%2B+++Cos%5B60+Pi%2F180%5D+Sin%5B25+Pi%2F180%5D+Cos%5B48+Pi%2F180%5D+Sin%5B-122+Pi%2F180%5D+%2B+++Sin%5B60+Pi%2F180%5D+Sin%5B48+Pi%2F180%5D

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos60^\circ\cos25^{\circ}\cos48^{\circ}\cos(-122^{\circ})+\cos60^{\circ}\sin25^{\circ}\cos48^{\circ}\sin(-122^{\circ})+\sin60^{\circ}\sin48^{\circ}=$$
$$=\cos60^{\circ}\cos48^{\circ}(\cos25^{\circ}\cos122^{\circ}-\sin25^{\circ}\sin122^{\circ})+\sin60^{\circ}\sin48^{\circ}=$$
$$=\cos60^{\circ}\cos48^{\circ}\cos147^{\circ}+\sin60^{\circ}\sin48^{\circ}$$
and $$\arccos\left(\cos60^{\circ}\cos48^{\circ}\cos147^{\circ}+\sin60^{\circ}\sin48^{\circ}\right)=68.7...^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Why is "cos 25 cos 122 - sin 25 sin 122" in parenthesis and why are both the 122s positive here? Also, where is the second cos 60 from part 1 and the second cos 48 from part 1?

Comment: @Science_Math I used $\cos(-x)=\cos{x}$, $\sin(-x)=-\sin{x}$ and $ab-ac=a(b-c).$